# How can I use icon from .eps file and load them on my site?

Tags: css, icons, eps, sprite-sheet

## I Have

a file`file.eps` that I downloaded from http://www.shutterstock.com/ , it looks like this :

[image]

---

## I want

to export all those icons into its own piece so that I can use them on my site.

---

## I've tried

doing this manually one-by-one it is very time-consuming, now I'm looking for a better way to export all of them.

---

## I got some questions

Is there any Mac application out there that help me export/slice my `file.eps` into multiple `icon.png` file ?

Should I even need to extract them ?

---

## My main goal are :

- load them on my website
- keep minimum HTTP request
- look awesome on retina display devices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure there is more than one way to achieve this kind of task, but this is how I get mine done. Here are my steps :

---

## 1. Convert .eps to .png

I did that by open my `file.eps` in Illustrator, and go to File > Save For Web > Select PNG-8 > Save. You should see it export to your desired destination.

---

## 2. Create Sprites Stylesheet

Go to http://www.spritecow.com/

I load my exported `file.png`, and select any objects, a correspond css code should be automatically generated for me like this :

[image]

---

## 3. Result

I selected multiple icons that I liked, and display them properly.

Finally, I put together my result :  [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/xuwcug3z/)

Hope this answer help someone like me.

Answer (score 1):

For those on a Mac, you can use the default program in `Preview`.

Once you open the image, go to File > Export > Format.

You can then select your desired format and there's also an option to choose where to save it to.

Hope this also helps :)